# Newton's Third Law is just wrong, can you see why?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

For every action there is an equally opposite reaction is flawed. Can you identify why?
The answer is simple enough and its simplicity makes it very hard to see, can you?

Comment: This is not a riddle-type website. Nor is it the Fermat's margin :) Although it should be noted  that Newton's third law is indeed flawed. It does not hold in electrodynamics.

Comment: I believe Newton’s third law is flawed because the action itself consumes some amount of energy resulting is less than you began with therefore the reaction cannot be equal.

Comment: Action and reaction are forces on two different bodies.

Comment: You say that this is not a riddle-type website while your site is based on questions. This appears to be in opposite to the intent

Comment: You posed a question like you already know the answer. It appears that you are just teasing the members of the website. It is completely valid to post a question that you already know the answer to if you believe it is valuable, but then there is an option to answer your own question.

Comment: *You say that this is not a riddle-type website while your site is based on questions. This appears to be in opposite to the intent* Ok, so we have a wisecrack on our hands, one who can't tell the difference between a question and a riddle...

Comment: *I believe [blahblahdiblah]* **believe** being the operative word here.

Comment: What other great insights do you have to share?

Comment: The answer provided by Neelim answers this question, simple Newtonian mechanics is not generally considered to be an area of physics that is open to much improvement.

Answer (score 6):

I guess you are considering that if there is an equal and opposite force, how is there any movement? The answer is that the equal and opposite forces are acting on two different bodies, and are causing movements on those bodies separately

Comment: +1 many people do not realize this and are confused by Newton's third law

Comment: Re, "...two different bodies..." Specifically, if A exerts force on B, then B must also exert force on A. If A and B are astronauts "floating" next to the space station, and A gives B a shove, then both B _and_ A will fly away from the station in opposite directions.

Comment: I believe, that in any action/reaction some energy is lost. 
The statement, The size of the forces on the first object equals the size of the force on the second object.
In my view “equal” cannot be equal, energy is lost in the action.

Comment: since energy is lost, it means that the sum of the forces is less than it would be if energy were not lost. But it doesn't mean that the forces are not equal and opposite. So if energy is lost, both forces are decreasing

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0LnbyjOyEQ8 in the above the balls should continue to hit each other and not slow down

Comment: *I believe, that in any action/reaction some energy is lost.* So if I push against an immobile wall and the wall pushes back there's energy lost? How, pray tell?

Comment: *in the above the balls should continue to hit each other and not [...]* The balls eventually stop because of loss of energy due to non-conservative forces, in particular friction. As a result with each 'cycle' some energy is lost, e.g. as sound. This doesn't prove what you claim in any sense of the word.

Comment: It is the equal and opposite force that is making the moving ball stop. For further clarification:
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/602200/conservation-of-momentum-in-a-newton-s-cradle-with-inelastic-collisions

Comment: The idea that a law that's been tested to destruction for several centuries can be disproved by a Utoob of Newton's Cradle shows a naivete rarely seen on these here pages.